# Компиляция скрипта в exe Anaconda 3

Tags: gui, компиляция, python-3.6, anaconda

Нужно сделать exe файл для использования на компьютерах без питона. 
Пытался cxfreezом и  pyinstallerом.Не получается ,выдает ошибки импорта,предела рекурсии,сх не импортирует кучу нужных файлов.Хотя сам скрипт рабочий.
Заодно расскажите,пожалуйста,как нужно поставлять файл ,если не получается его в ехе перевести.
Совсем уже отчаялся,никак не выходит сделать исполняемым.Спасибо всем неравнодушным,кто откликнется.
[image: После того,как вставил недостающие файлы из xlwt в build].[image: pyinstaller]

```
    C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\Distribute> C:\Anaconda3\python.exe setup.py build
running build
running build_exe

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
        module.run()
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
        exec(code, m.__dict__)
      File "GMIND.py", line 2, in <module>
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwt\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from .Worksheet import Worksheet
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 38, in <module>
        from .Row import Row
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 8, in <module>
        from . import ExcelFormula
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwt\ExcelFormula.py", line 3, in <module>
        from . import ExcelFormulaParser, ExcelFormulaLexer
    ImportError: cannot import name 'ExcelFormulaParser'
```

а вот код setup.py:

```
  from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
setup(
    name = "GM",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "GM",
    executables = [Executable("GMIND.py")])
```

Comment: Пожалуйста приведите сообщение ошибки текстом, используйте для изменения вопроса кнопку "править".

Comment: Сам скрипт работает. Версия питона 3.6.5.(анаконда).Использую numpy,sys,xlwt,matplotlib,PyQt5.